# PWC1232: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke

Tags: jsf, glassfish, infinite-loop, facesservlet

I am using jsf 2.1 (mojara) with glassfish 3.1 , and my web .xml looks like :

```
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>NewFile.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
```

I am getting this error

> 2015-03-11T21:40:15.054+0530|Warning:
>   ApplicationDispatcher[/JSFProject] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for
>   servlet Faces Servlet threw exception javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   PWC1232: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:772)

Comment: This particular error in combination with [jsp] tag on the question suggests that you're actually using JSP instead of Facelets (XHTML). Is this true? If not, why exactly the [jsp] tag on the question then?

Comment: @BalusC : No i am not using jsp any where ... But this error is frustrating ....:(

Comment: Don't use [jsp] tag then. Are there any JARs in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`? If so, which?

Comment: these are the jars that are present :commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-el-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
javax.servlet.jar
jsf-api.jar
jsf-impl.jar
junit-4.12.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
myfaces-api-1.1.5.jar
myfaces-impl-1.1.5.jar
poi-3.12-beta1-20150228.jar
poi-examples-3.12-beta1-20150228.jar
poi-excelant-3.12-beta1-20150228.jar
poi-ooxml-3.12-beta1-20150228.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-beta1-20150228.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.12-beta1-20150228.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

Comment: Where did you read/learn that you should be adding those JARs?

Comment: @BalusC... just googled the required jars ... and i read your post for t:uploadfile options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem suggests that you're using JSF 1.x, not JSF 2.x. JSF 1.x uses JSP as default view technology whereas JSF 2.x uses Facelets as default view technology. And, JSF 1.x has the known bug ("feature") that its `FacesServlet` would run in an infinite loop when it's being mapped on same suffix URL pattern as the physical view file.

And indeed, your `/WEB-INF/lib` contains among others the following JARs which absolutely do not belong there. GlassFish as being a full fledged Java EE container already ships with Servlet and JSF API/impl out the box.

- `javax.servlet.jar` (Servlet API; already supplied by GlassFish!)
- `jsf-api.jar` (Mojarra 1.x; GlassFish already supplies Mojarra 2.x!)
- `jsf-impl.jar` (Mojarra 1.x; GlassFish already supplies Mojarra 2.x!)
- `myfaces-api-1.1.5.jar` (MyFaces 1.x; GlassFish already supplies Mojarra 2.x!)
- `myfaces-impl-1.1.5.jar` (MyFaces 1.x; GlassFish already supplies Mojarra 2.x!)

Get rid of them. Even then, you should not be mixing multiple JSF implementations in one webapp.

Comment: Clean, rebuild, redeploy, restart. And, make sure that your `faces-config.xml` root declaration conforms at least JSF 2.0.

Comment: got it .. tomahawk20-1.1.10 jar mismatch ...now its working !! thanks a lot @BalusC